# Evaluate macros on \foreach arguments

Tags: macros, foreach, etoolbox

I have a large `\foreach` loop, and need to evaluate macros on the arguments. (These are string comparison macros, but maybe that doesn't matter.) Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\process[1]{\ifstrequal{#1}{Fridge}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {Fridge,Badger} {\process{\a} }
\end{document}
```

This produces the output `UNEQUAL UNEQUAL`. My desired output is `EQUAL UNEQUAL`.

In my real example I'm doing a simultaneous iteration over multiple variables (`\foreach \a/\b in ...`), and my macros take multiple parameters, not just one.

I'm not *completely* clueless; I know why this is happening, and I've tried hundreds of combinations of `\expandafter`, `\edef`, and so on, but without any success. I find this aspect of LaTeX extremely hard to understand.

Comment: `\ifstrequal` does not expand its arguments.

Comment: Hi @egreg, thanks for your comment. I don't really know what that means. I don't have to use `\ifstrequal`, I'd be happy to use some other macro that lets me test an argument for string equality.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\process[1]{\expandafter\ifstrequal\expandafter{#1}{Fridge}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {Fridge,Badger} {\process{\a} }
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ulrike, this worked perfectly for me, even when I nest the macros.

Answer (score 5):

The manual of `etoolbox` says (section 3.6.3)

> `\ifstrequal{⟨string⟩}{⟨string⟩}{⟨true⟩}{⟨false⟩}`
>   Compares two strings and executes `⟨true⟩` if they are equal, and `⟨false⟩` otherwise. The strings are not expanded in the test and the comparison is category code agnostic. Control sequence tokens in any of the `⟨string⟩` arguments will be detokenized and treated as strings.

In other words, you are comparing

```
\a
```

(a two character string) with `Fridge` and they're not equal at all. With `expl3` you can access an expanding string comparison function:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tikz}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifstrequal}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\process[1]{\xifstrequal{#1}{Fridge}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}}

\begin{document}

\foreach \a in {Fridge,Badger} {\process{\a} }

\end{document}
```

A full `expl3` version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifstrequal}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\listforeach}{mm}
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand\process[1]{\xifstrequal{#1}{Fridge}{EQUAL}{UNEQUAL}}

\begin{document}

\listforeach{Fridge,Badger}{\process{#1} }

\end{document}
```

Instead of using some dummy control sequence, the current item is denoted by `#1`.

Both codes produce the same output.

[image]

Comment: He is not comparing `\process{\a}` but only `\a` with Fridge.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, that's right.

Comment: Hi Greg, thanks for your solution! I don't know what `expl3` is, and when I tried your code, my compiler didn't like it.

Comment: @JamieVicary First update your TeX distribution.