# Use datatool input to enable beamer frame

Tags: beamer, presentations, datatool

I want to use the value of a flag imported from a datatool database (stored in an external .csv file) to enable (or disable) a beamer frame.

The .csv file is of the form:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv} 
test enable
test1 ok
test2 ok
test3 ok
\end{filecontents*}
```

Imported into a datatool database :

```
\DTLloaddb{test}{test.csv}
```

My command:

```
\newcommand{\frameIsEnabled}[1]{\ifstrequal{#1}{ok}{1}{0}}
```

I'm trying to use the `\frameIsEnabled` command to enable the frame fetching the database value:

```
\begin{frame}<presentation: \frameIsEnabled{\DTLfetch{test}{test1}{enable}}>
```

But latex is not happy. I suppose there is something wrong related to the format of the fetched value `\DTLfetch{test}{test1}{enable}`.

If I display it (i.e. in a table or text) it returns zero (i.e. the comparison with the string "ok" returns `false`).

Here's a minimal example to reproduce my problem.

***Example 1***, to verify the comparison of the "enable" flag with the string "ok":

```
\documentclass[6pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Malmoe}}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv} 
testName, enable
test1, ok
test2, ok
test3, ok
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\frameIsEnabled}[1]{\ifstrequal{#1}{ok}{1}{0}}

\DTLloaddb[headers={testName, enable}]{testList}{test.csv}

\title{My Presentation}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}<presentation:1>
    Test1 enable flag is "\DTLfetch{testList}{testName}{test1}{enable}".

    Comparison with "ok" returns \frameIsEnabled{\DTLfetch{testList}{testName}{test1}{enable}}.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Within this code, the `\frameIsEnabled` command will return `0`, while the desired output is `1`

***Example 2***, using the fetched value from the database to enable the frame:

```
\documentclass[6pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Malmoe}}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv} 
testName, enable
test1, ok
test2, ok
test3, ok
\end{filecontents*}

\newcommand{\frameIsEnabled}[1]{\ifstrequal{#1}{ok}{1}{0}}

\DTLloaddb[headers={testName, enable}]{testList}{test.csv}

\title{My Presentation}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}<presentation:\frameIsEnabled{\DTLfetch{testList}{testName}{test1}{enable}}>
    Test1 enable flag is "\DTLfetch{testList}{testName}{test1}{enable}".

    Comparison with "ok" returns \frameIsEnabled{\DTLfetch{testList}{testName}{test1}{enable}}.
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This code will throw the error:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@@@temp. \end{frame}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer / suggestion. I've edited my question with a code sample to reproduce the bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the commands you use are not expandable. To worka round this problem one can combine https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386503/36296 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/335489/36296

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Malmoe}}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents*}{test.csv} 
testName, enable
test1, ok
test2, ok
test3, ok
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\xifstrequal}{mmmm}
 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\DTLfetchsave}[5]{%
  \edtlgetrowforvalue{#2}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#3}}{#4}%
  \dtlgetentryfromcurrentrow{\dtlcurrentvalue}{\dtlcolumnindex{#2}{#5}}%
  \let#1\dtlcurrentvalue
}

\newcommand{\frameIsEnabled}[1]{\xifstrequal{#1}{ok}{1}{0}}

\DTLloaddb[headers={testName, enable}]{testList}{test.csv}

\title{My Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}


\DTLfetchsave{\temp}{testList}{testName}{test1}{enable}%
\begin{frame}<presentation:\frameIsEnabled{\temp}>
    Test1 enable flag is "\DTLfetch{testList}{testName}{test1}{enable}".

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```